# Trace of nilpotent matrix over a ring

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and $n$ a positive integer.

Let $A\in \mathfrak{M}_n(R)$ such that there exists $m\in \mathbb N$, for which $A^m=0$.

Is it true that there exists $\ell\in \mathbb N$, such that $\bigl(\text{tr}(A)\bigr)^\ell=0$ ?

Remark : It is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: See http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimhtml/gert.html for an answer.

Comment: Note: this fails for non-commutative rings. It suffices to consider $2\times2$ matrices with entries in $M_2(\Bbb R)$

Comment: @grinberg I like the proof that you quote, using multilinear algebra and giving a bound for $l$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $\mathfrak{p}$ is any prime ideal of $R$, then $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is a domain. We can embed it in its fraction field, then in an algebraic closure. Then your matrix mod $\mathfrak{p}$ is triangularisable, with of course eigenvalues $0$.

Hence, the reduction mod $\mathfrak{p}$ of your matrix has vanishing trace. Since this is true for every prime ideal, this shows that the trace of $A$ is in the intersection of all prime ideals of $R$, that is in the nilradical of $R$, which is the ideal of nilpotent elements of $R$.

This concludes the proof.

Comment: Very neat, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. But if you know some multilinear algebra, have a look at the proof quoted by grinberg.