# The square of trace is not contained in the ideal generated by $A^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A=\left[\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{array}\right]$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix over a field $k$, and $A^2=0$. Then we have four homogeneous polynomials in $a,b,c,d$:

$$
a^2+bc, \quad c(a+d),\quad b(a+d),\quad d^2+bc.
$$

Let $I$ be the ideal generated by above polynomials. Then, by Nullstellensatz, the trace of $A$, $a+d$, is contained in $\sqrt I$. I'd like to find the smallest degree $r$ such that $(a+d)^r\in I$. I've worked out that $(a+d)^3\in I$, but I can't show $(a+d)^2\in I$ or $(a+d)^2\notin I$.

Any hint please?

Comment: You can use Groebner bases, see the calculation in [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialReduce%5B%28a%2Bd%29%5E2%2C+%7Bb+c+%2B+d%5E2%2C+a+d%5E2+%2B+d%5E3%2C+a+c+%2B+c+d%2C+a+b+%2B+b+d%2C+a%5E2+-+d%5E2%7D%2C%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%2Cd%7D%5D). The answer is "No". Note that the reduction is w. r. to a Groebner basis of the ideal generated by the $4$ relations above.

Comment: @orangeskid Can you make that into an answer?

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff: Just did that, thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mechanical way to check whether an element of a polynomial ring belongs to an ideal with given generators. It first finds  a Groebner basis of the ideal ( wr to a certain ordering), and then performs a reduction of the element w r to the Groebner basis, with a unique remainder. The element belongs to the ideal, if and only if the remainder is $0$.

The first calculation in [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7Ba%5E2%20%2B%20b%20c%2C%20b%28a%2Bd%29%2C%20c%28a%2Bd%29%2C%20d%5E2%2B%20b%20c%7D%2C%20%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%2Cd%7D%5D) finds the Groebner basis
$$\{b c + d^2, a d^2 + d^3, a c + c d, a b + b d, a^2 - d^2\}$$
and the second [calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialReduce%5B%28a%2Bd%29%5E2%2C%20%7Bb%20c%20%2B%20d%5E2%2C%20a%20d%5E2%20%2B%20d%5E3%2C%20a%20c%20%2B%20c%20d%2C%20a%20b%20%2B%20b%20d%2C%20a%5E2%20-%20d%5E2%7D%2C%7Ba%2Cb%2Cc%2Cd%7D%5D) produces the remainder of $(a+d)^2$  wr to the above basis. The remainder is $2 a d + 2 d^2$, so not $0$ ( we assume $k$ of characteristic $0$).
Therefore, $(a+d)^2$ does not belong to the ideal.

Note that with similar calculations we check that the determinant $ a d - b c$ does not belong to the ideal, but its square $(a d - b c)^2$ does (!).

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108057/nipotent-matrix-over-a-ring) is also related, and there are further links there.

$\bf{Added:}$

There is a simpler solution to the problem. Say we are trying to solve the system
$$a^2 + b c = d^2 + b c = b(a+d)= c(a+d)=0$$
in a commutative ring $R$.  We can get a particular solution if we take $b=c=0$. Then the system becomes
$$a^2 = b^2 = 0$$
Now, does every solution $(a,b)$ to this latter system satisfy $(a+b)^2=0$?  We know that $(a+b)$ is nilpotent, but maybe not of order $2$. And indeed, we can see a simple example in the ring $R = k[x,y]/(x^2, y^2)$, where $2 \ne 0$ in $k$. Take $a = x$, $b=y$, and we have $(x+y)^2 = x^2+ 2 x y + y^2 = 2 x y \ne 0$.  Note also that $a d - b c = a d = x y$ again is not zero in this ring $R$, therefore $ad - b c$ does not belong to the ideal with the given generators ( if it did, then any solution of the system also satisfies  $a d - b c = 0$).

Comment: Thank you! I tried to compute the basis by hand but soon it became too complicated. I can only verify that $(a+d)^2$ has remainder $2ad+d^2$ over the claimed basis.

Comment: @Ping Wan: Armed with a bit of Groebner bases theory, it should not be hard to check that what they software produced is a basis ( there is the Groebner criterion). One just must understand what is the assumed monomial order in the default option.

Comment: I read [Grobner Bases Tutorial](https://dacox.people.amherst.edu/lectures/gb1.handout.pdf) and applying the SR criterion I verified that this basis is a Grobner basis for $I$. I'm satisfied for now. Thank you again!